# Tux with Sinatra cannot load

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

Pretty new to Sinatra, but I am following this tutorial to set up a simple blog site with some static pages: http://danneu.com/posts/15-a-simple-blog-with-sinatra-and-active-record-some-useful-tools/

I created the gemfile which contains this:

```
# Gemfile
source :rubygems

gem "sinatra"
gem "sqlite3"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"

group :development do
  gem "shotgun"
  gem "tux"
end
```

I then installed using `bundle install`

My config.ru looks like this:

```
#config.ru
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

But when I try to run `tux` I get the following error:

```
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.0/lib/ripl/rack.rb:38:in `eval': cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
    from (eval):2:in `block in initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from (eval):1:in `new'
    from (eval):1:in `initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.0/lib/ripl/rack.rb:38:in `eval'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.0/lib/ripl/rack.rb:38:in `initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.0/lib/ripl/rack.rb:18:in `new'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.0/lib/ripl/rack.rb:18:in `rack'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.0/lib/ripl/rack.rb:9:in `before_loop'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-multi_line-0.3.1/lib/ripl/multi_line.rb:18:in `before_loop'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-0.7.0/lib/ripl/readline.rb:6:in `before_loop'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-0.7.0/lib/ripl/completion.rb:5:in `before_loop'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-0.7.0/lib/ripl/shell.rb:34:in `loop'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-0.7.0/lib/ripl/runner.rb:49:in `start'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ripl-0.7.0/lib/ripl/runner.rb:31:in `run'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/tux-0.3.0/bin/tux:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/tux:23:in `load'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/tux:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I have `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]`

Comment: Post the line where you ran tux--the whole thing.

Comment: Are you running `bundle exec tux`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is this:

```
cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
```

That error is saying that tux cannot find a file called app.rb in the current directory.  tux is looking for that file because your config.ru says this:

```
config.ru
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

See how it mentions a file called "./app"?  Well, the "tutorial" doesn't show you the screenshot for that file until after it shows you the screenshot for tux.  So create the app.rb file, then run tux.

Also change your Gemfile from this:

```
source :rubygems
```

to this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

(When you did `.../blog$ bundle install` Bundler should have given you a warning about that.)

Another error you will encounter further on:

In tux, it says to do this:

```
>> p = new_record?
```

That should be:

```
>> p.new_record?
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick. I couldn't find many Sinatra tutorials, this one seemed the most geared toward what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super-familiar with config.ru, but one possible problem is that you are using `require` for a relative file path. Changing the first line to -

```
require_relative "./app"
```

might help.